# How to rename a table and some columns in production

Tags: mysql, .net, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4

I am using Entity Framework to handle the database in a server application. The server application is deployed to multiple nodes sitting behind a load balancer. I have now discovered the need to rename some of the tables and some of the table columns in the database. The problem is that I will need to do this without any down-time.

If I was writing my own database layer I could simply check the structure of the database and then run different code depending on if the database structure was upgraded or not and then I could potentially have 0% downtime.

Is it possible to do something like this in entity framework 4 or how do I actually make database changes in production with entity framework? I have searched the web for any solution but to no success. I have also considered having 2 entity framework instances in my app but the amount of code I have to write to switch between them would be far too much and error prone.

So to summarize the question:
Is there any way to rename tables and columns in a database in a production environment using Entity Framework 4 and without any downtime whatsoever?

**EDIT**
A new idea I got would be to create a view in place of the old table with the old naming scheme referencing the new table. I dont know if this will work. For it to work Entity Framework needs to accept this view like it would be a normal table. Could this be a good idea? Anyone tried anything like this with EF4 ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay! Here is what thought I got -
Create new table in DB than renaming and build EntityFramework solution on that.

You need to deploy this by taking one server off from loadbalancer, update it,point entity framework code to new table structure and then again attach to loadbalancer.

Make the same procedure for all the servers in loadbalancer one by one. Once all are up with updated patch then sync old table and new table and then just delete old table. I am suggesting synching these tables so that you have all the data without data loss might happen in above process.

Comment: I have also thought in the lines of this but since each request can end up in either node and it is just a normal table I cannot merge the tables since I will never know which row is newer

Comment: Thats why I suggested synchronization between Old and new table needed. You can just add up values in new tables using Merge operation in SQL for the rows which are not maching. This will be manual process and can be completed when load on server is minimal.

Comment: Sorry, that is not possible since server load is constant and I can never know which rows are right.

Comment: No issues. Please let me know if you find any better option. Would be curious to hear that.

Comment: Initial tests seem to suggest that using a view would actually work. It seem to work in a compiled .exe file, but if I try to update the model in entity framework it fails. But that should not be an issue. Will continue testing this.

Comment: As long as you are owner of this view should not be a problem but if you are thinking of outsourcing maintenance work then problem will start arising.